# .NET Core session variables temporarily gone when page is refreshed

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-6.0

I implemented a custom authentication scheme in my ASP.NET Core 6 based web application with Angular frontend as described [here](https://referbruv.com/blog/implementing-custom-authentication-scheme-and-handler-in-aspnet-core-3x/).

Inside my `AuthenticationHandler`, I read some variables from the current session which I need in order to authenticate the user. It basically works like this:

```
protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
{
    try
    {
        ISession session;

        try
        {
            session = this.Context.Session;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.NoResult());
        }

        // Get user information from session

        if (/*User information incomplete or null*/)
        {
            this.Logger.LogDebug("No user credentials found in session");
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.NoResult());
        }

        Claim[] claims = new[] {
            new Claim(...),
            new Claim(...) };

        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, nameof(MyAuthHandler));
        AuthenticationTicket? ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), this.Scheme.Name);

        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Check logged in exception"));
    }
}
```

When I run and debug the app locally within Kestrel, everything works just fine, but when it is hosted on an IIS, I cannot refresh the page after successfully logging in.
Strangely, it seems like every time the fallback route is used (which happens when the route belongs to something in the Angular frontend instead of the backend API), the session is empty. As a result, when I successfully login via the frontend and then refresh the page, the refresh does not work and I get a 401 error returned by the webserver.
One example of when this happens is when I login, get redirected to the "dashboard" route of the Angular app and then refresh the page. When I then check the logs, this is what is being logged:

```
INFO  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics [(null)]: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://<url>/dashboard - -
DEBUG Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware [(null)]: The request path /dashboard does not match a supported file type
DEBUG Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher [(null)]: 1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/dashboard'
DEBUG Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher [(null)]: Endpoint 'Fallback {**slug}' with route pattern '{**slug}' is valid for the request path '/dashboard'
DEBUG Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware [(null)]: Request matched endpoint 'Fallback {**slug}'
DEBUG MyApp.BusinessLogic.Authentication.MyAuthHandler [(null)]: No user credentials found in session
DEBUG MyApp.BusinessLogic.Authentication.MyAuthHandler [(null)]: AuthenticationScheme: MyAuthScheme was not authenticated.
INFO  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService [(null)]: Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
```

I'd also like to point out that the session variables are not actually gone. As soon as I manually navigate to the root path of the web application, everything works just fine again and I am still logged in.

Here is how the app is configured in my `Program.cs` file:

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Logging.AddLog4Net();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(MyAuthDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddScheme<MyAuthSchemeOptions, MyAuthHandler>(
        MyAuthDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => { });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
    options.Cookie.Path = "/api/";
});

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseSession();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Map("api/{**slug}", HandleApiFallback);

app.MapFallbackToFile("{**slug}", "index.html");

app.Run();

static Task HandleApiFallback(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Why are the session variables suddenly gone in this scenario and how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this option caused the problem:

```
options.Cookie.Path = "/api/"
```

I just do not know why this only caused problems on the IIS and not when debugging the application locally.